# AppGyver plugins without build service

Tags: cordova, steroids, appgyver

I am working with AppGyver and Steroids to develop a cross-browser app and I'm now at the point where I want to integrate a certain push notification plugin, namely the [Pushwoosh plugin](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin).

I understand that I have to go through the AppGyver Build service to include this plugin. However, this process would really hinder development; namely, I would have to deploy the entire Steroids project every time I make a change, and download a Scanner build after waiting several minutes for it to build.

Is there a way to bypass the AppGyver Build service and include plugins directly for local development? It would streamline the development process greatly.

If it is not possible, why not?

Answer (score 0):

The way to use custom plugins in local development is to build a custom Scanner app using the build service with your plugins.

See "Developing locally with custom plugins" at http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/plugins/configuring-custom-plugins/